# Appium- Elements not detected inside an View (Carousel View)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Guys does anyone know the reason behind y appium inspector doesn't detect elements present in a View (Carousel View)?
How to handle such kind of elements?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot and the page source of such an element?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have checked `Show Disabled` that is visible in top left corner of Appium inspector.

If it is checked and there are still some views missing, then you can not simply access them without changing the app source code.